# Sushiswap Router Contract Address on Sepolia Public Testnet?

Tags: testnets, sushiswap, sepolia

I'm trying to interact with Sushiswap on the Sepolia public testnet, and I already found the Uniswap Router contract address. However, I can't seem to locate the Sushiswap Router contract address for this testnet. Does anyone know where I can find the Sushiswap Router contract address deployed on the Sepolia testnet?